# Introduction pages for categories in Pelican

Tags: python, pelican

I would like to build my personal web pages in Pelican, but I am missing one functionality. I would love to have an *introductory page* for some/all categories on the pages.

For example - I would like to build a page for my grant project, where posts are related to activities and/or published papers, **but** I would also like a single *page* saying something about the grant project and keep this page as the title page of this category.

Is this possible (easily) in Pelican framework? If not, can you suggest better static pages framework that works in combination Markdown+Python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHoff it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually very easy with pelican. The plugin [Auto Pages](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/autopages) defines three extra content folders: One for authors, one for categories and one for tags.

Say you, John Smith, wanted to have extra information about your person when clicking on your name. Then, you would add a file called `authors/john-smith{.rst|.md}` with this extra information. No HTML, but only the contents you want to provide about your person. These contents are then read in, transformed and presented to the template engine as `author.page`.

Now it is about your templates to also use this variable.
In my theme, I simply modified `theme/templates/author.html` to not show the combination of "featured article" and "other articles" related to my author, but to show `author.page.content` and "all articles" related to my author instead.

Short extract of my `theme/templates/author.html`:

```
<aside id="featured" class="body">
      <article>
          <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ author.url }}">{{ author }}</a></h1>
          {{ author.page.content }}
      </article>
</aside>
<section id="content" class="body">
      <!-- removed the apostrophe for SO highlighting reasons-->
      <h1>Authors articles</h1>
      <hr/>
      <ol id="posts-list" class="hfeed" start="{{ articles_paginator.per_page - 1}}">
      {% for article in articles_page.object_list %}
          <li><article class="hentry">
              <header>
                  <h1><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}" rel="bookmark"
                          title="Permalink to {{ article.title|striptags }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h1>
              </header>

              {% include 'article_infos.html' %}
              {{ article.summary }}
              <a class="readmore" href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ article.url }}">read more</a>
              {% include 'comments.html' %}
          </article></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ol>
      {% if articles_page.has_other_pages() %}
          {% include 'pagination.html' %}
      {% endif %}
</section>
```

You can do the exact same thing for categories and tags using the procedure described above. For the template, just use the existing `index.html` and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Is this plugin still valid in 2021? I found the last update to be dated back in 2018, so I'm not sure if it is recommendable to use the plugin.

Comment: @DanijelaPopović I honestly don't know since I have not used pelican in the recent years.