# How to make individual index.html file for each category in pelican

Tags: python, pelican

I'm new to `pelican` and I recently made my personal blogs website

- My website link : [hosted on github pages](https://shah-aayush.github.io/)
- Source code : [on github](https://github.com/Shah-Aayush/Shah-Aayush.github.io)

  > website is hosted on `gh-pages` branch with the help of `ghp-import`

Here I want to generate custom category welcome/homepage for each category. I don't want to display all the articles of that specific category. I tried this by creating index.html file in the each specific folder of category but it didn't worked. Also searched on SO and found some related answers but I cannot figure out what to do in my case
Here are those questions (*Mentioning it cos maybe they are helpful*) :

- [How do I choose a category page to be the home page for a Pelican site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363180/how-do-i-choose-a-category-page-to-be-the-home-page-for-a-pelican-site)
- [How to customize individual category pages in Pelican](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002801/how-to-customize-individual-category-pages-in-pelican)
- [Introduction pages for categories in Pelican](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385708/introduction-pages-for-categories-in-pelican)

## What I want?

- For example, In `Shah-Aayush.github.io/content/notes/` category, I don't want to display  all the pages reside in this notes category and giving `more` button to expand and see each category. instead I want to display custom introduction page which is `index.md`. so when I click on `notes` category on my [website](https://shah-aayush.github.io/) it opens the default generated `https://shah-aayush.github.io/category/notes.html` page but I want to generate `https://shah-aayush.github.io/my-notes.html` page which is [index.md](https://github.com/Shah-Aayush/Shah-Aayush.github.io/blob/master/content/notes/index.md).
- Another example : in this profile category, I want to display the contents of `profiles.md` not displaying [all contents reside in profile folder/category](https://github.com/Shah-Aayush/Shah-Aayush.github.io/tree/master/content/profiles) the `10ff.md`,  `spotify.md`, `profiles.md` and giving `more` button to expand each.
  so what does it display now when I click on profile : https://shah-aayush.github.io/category/profiles.html
  What I want it do display when I click profile category : https://shah-aayush.github.io/my-profiles.html

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you saying for each category, you'd like to display some content before the posts in that category?

If so, I think you would need to make a category extension, which would merge category specific additional content and then override the category template.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question. The Pelican metadata has a field called `save_as` on the documentation page. I have used this feature on my own website.

https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/content.html

On your `index.md` file, you can have a metadata line like this,

```
Title: My super title
save_as: my-notes.html
Date: 2010-12-03 10:20
Modified: 2010-12-05 19:30
Category: Python
Tags: pelican, publishing
Slug: my-super-post
Authors: Alexis Metaireau, Conan Doyle
Summary: Short version for index and feeds
```

The second line will direct Pelican to save the output as `my-notes.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat messy, but working solution. Here is the relevant part of my configuration file.

```py
import os
from jinja2 import Environment, ChoiceLoader, FileSystemLoader
from markdown import Markdown


MARKDOWN = {
    "extension_configs": {
        "markdown.extensions.attr_list": {},
        "markdown.extensions.def_list": {},
        "markdown.extensions.footnotes": {},
        "markdown.extensions.md_in_html": {},
        "markdown.extensions.meta": {},
        "markdown.extensions.nl2br": {},
        "markdown.extensions.tables": {},
        "markdown.extensions.toc": {"title": "", "toc_depth": "2-6"},
        "pymdownx.emoji": {"title": "long"},
        "pymdownx.caret": {},
        "pymdownx.tilde": {},
        "pymdownx.mark": {},
        "pymdownx.tasklist": {},
        "pymdownx.details": {},
        "pymdownx.superfences": {"preserve_tabs": True},
        "pymdownx.highlight": {"css_class": "highlight", "use_pygments": True, "noclasses": True, "pygments_style": "Dani_dark"},
        "customblocks": {"generators": {"question": "customblocks.custom_generators:question"}},"linkcard": {}}},
        "tablespan": {},
        "mdx_include_lines": {"base_path": "content/code", "encoding": "utf-8", "line_nums": False},
        "markdown_include.include": {"encoding": "utf-8"},
    },
    "output_format": "html5"
}

md_extensions = [e for e in MARKDOWN["extension_configs"].keys()]
md = Markdown(extensions=md_extensions, extension_configs=MARKDOWN["extension_configs"], output_format="html5")
# of course, you should define the extensions according to your needs, the example just shows how I do it


def category_details(cat_name):
    if not cat_name in CATEGORY_DETAILS.keys():
        return ""
    cat_details_obj = CATEGORY_DETAILS[cat_name]
    if cat_details_obj.long_description != "":
        env = Environment(loader=ChoiceLoader([FileSystemLoader(os.path.join("themes", "Elegant", "templates"))]), **JINJA_ENVIRONMENT)
        jinja_processed = env.from_string(cat_details_obj.long_description).render()
        return md.convert(jinja_processed)
    else:
        return cat_details_obj.short_description

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = {"extensions": ["jinja2.ext.do", "jinja2.ext.i18n"]}
JINJA_FILTERS = {
    "cat_details": category_details,
}

CATEGORY_DETAILS_PATH = "cat_details"


class CategoryDetails:
    name = ""
    short_description = ""
    long_description = ""

    def __init__(self, name, short_description="", desc_filename=""):
        self.name = name
        self.short_description = short_description
        desc_file_path = os.path.join(PATH, CATEGORY_DETAILS_PATH, desc_filename)
        if not desc_filename in ["", " ", None] and os.path.isfile(desc_file_path):
            with open(desc_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                self.long_description = f.read()
        else:
            self.long_description = self.short_description


CATEGORY_DETAILS = {
    "Books": CategoryDetails("Books", "An awesome list of books to read and enjoy :)", "Books.txt"),
    "Katalonski - Català": CategoryDetails("Katalonski - Català", "Una llengua boniquíssima! :heart:"),
    "Francés/DuoLingo": CategoryDetails("Francés/DuoLingo", "Notas, vocabularios y más cosas del curso de francés en DuoLingo", "francés_DuoLingo.txt"),
}
```

As you guess, the next step is to create the `cat_details` folder and a .txt for every category, add the category to the `CATEGORY_DETAILS` dictionary, and then use the created filter in your template, for example in `index.html`:

```
{% if category %}
{{ category.name|cat_details|safe }}<hr />
{% endif %}
```

The only possible inconvenient is that this doesn't remove the articles list. The articles from the category will appear after the category details. To solve this, you may tweak your template. :)

I said it's messy... :)
There is, undouptedly, a better solution. And yes, this was made using folder structure for categories, but it should work with metadata, too.